# Dovecot - password query syntax error

Tags: mysql, postfix, amazon-ec2, dovecot, mariadb

Whenever Thunderbird attempts to connect to my server I receive an error in the maillog of

> dovecot: auth-worker(32527): Error: sql(admin,xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,): Password query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '<80><98>adminâ<80><99>' at line 1

Despite changing the password_query value in the "dovecot-sql.conf.ext" file I still get the same result, even if the where statement instead just selects "username = 'admin'".

(this is also the case with any other username e.g. "<80><98>usernameâ<80><99>")

```
driver = mysql
 
connect = host=127.0.0.1 dbname=postfix user=mailadmin
password=xxxxxxx
 
password_query = SELECT username AS user, password FROM mailbox WHERE
user = ‘%u’
 
iterate_query = SELECT username AS user FROM mailbox
```

And I have also checked that dovecot is actually using that file by changing the connection settings so that it's unable to login.

I am out of ideas as to what would cause the 'â' to appear at the end of the username and as to what the actual syntax error is.